# How to access a JSON string inside a JSON string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

my JSON string:

```
[{ "foo":"bar", "foo2":"[{ "test":"test", "test2":"test2" }]" }]
```

i want to get the values of `foo2` as a new JSON string.

i have tried these code but it wont work:

```
myObj[1]["test"];
```

Comment: You only have a single item in the outer array. Also, if you have a JSON, then you need to parse it with `JSON.parse`. (Otherwise, you don't have a JSON, you just have an object)

Comment: i have tried parsing the value but it always outputs `undefined`

Comment: simple googling can solve the problem, @winmar014 please do a search first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get the values of foo2 as a new JSON string

```js
var myObj = [{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo2": '[{ "test":"test", "test2":"test2" }]' /* replaced enclosing quotes " with ' */
}];
console.log(myObj[0]['foo2']); /* replaced 1 with 0 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the foo2 first then Test from foo2 myObj[0]['foo2'][0]["test"];

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo2": '[{ "test":"test", "test2":"test2" }]'
}];
var foo2 = JSON.parse(obj[0]['foo2']);
console.log(foo2[0]['test']);
```